# Choose appropriate HTTP status codes in controversial situations or introduce subcodes?

Tags: api, http, rest, http-status-codes

I am developing iOS application running against a remote server, having another developer behind it. The project and an API draft we are writing are in initial phase.

The problem we are faced with is that we are not satisfied with existing amount of conventional status codes described by HTTP/REST specifications: there are cases where we are uncertain about what code to pick up.

Examples to provide minimal context:

1. Server-side validation errors. Fx. Client-side validations are ok, but server API has recently been changed slightly, so a server should return something indicating that it is exactly the validation problem.
2. An attempt to register user that already exists. SO topics do not provide any precise point on that.
3. A user is registered, and tries to log in without having the password confirmation procedure accomplished.

Two obvious approaches we see here:

1. Use fx 400 error for the cases when an appropriate conventional status code could not be found. This will lead us to parsing error text messages from JSON responses. Obviously, this approach will introduce superfluous complication in a client-side code.
2. Create our own sub-codes system and rely on it in our code. This one involves too much artificial conventions, which will lead us towards becoming too opinionated and arbitrary.

Feeling that the number of such cases is going to grow, we are thinking about an introduction of custom sub-codes in JSON responses our server should give (i.e. choose the second approach).

What I'm asking here:

What are the recommended approaches, strategies, even glues or hacks for these kinds of situations?

What are pros-cons of moving away from strictly following REST/HTTP conventions for status codes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For validation problems, I use 422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV; RFC 4918)
The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.  This is because the request did not fail because of malformed syntax, but because of semantics.

Then in order to communicate you just need to decide on your errors format, so for situation 1 if there is a required field you might return a 422 with the following.

```
{
  "field": ["required"]
}
```

I would treat number two as a validation problem, since really it is a validation problem on username, so a 422 with the following.

```
{
  "username": ["conflict"]
}
```

Number three I would treat as a 403 Forbidden because passing an authorization header will not help and will be forbidden until they do something other than pass credentials.

You could do something like [oauth2](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31.html#token-errors) does and return a human readable description, a constant that people can code against that further clarifies the error and a uri for more information.

```
{
  "error": "unfinished_registration",
  "error_description": "Must finish the user registration process", 
  "error_uri": "http://yourdocumentation.com"
}
```

Note: you will find that people disagree on what http codes map to what situation and if 422 should be used since is part of the WebDAV extensions, and that is fine, the *most* important thing you can do is document what the codes mean and be consistent rather than being perfect with what they mean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially for the gotcha about the sub-codes as text constants. I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as "sub-codes" in HTTP (Microsoft IIS is clearly violating the spec, and should be flogged).

If there's an appropriate status code, use it; *don't* say "this status code means that in my application" because that's losing the value of generic status codes; you might as well design your own protocol.

After that, if you need to refine the semantics of the status code, use headers and/or the body.

Answer (score 2):

For the use cases you have described, you could use these error codes:

1) 400 Bad Request

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

2) 409 Conflict

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the     resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough
>
> information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be possible and is not required.
>
> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For example, if versioning were being used and the entity being PUT included changes to a resource which conflict with those made by an earlier (third-party) request, the server might use the 409 response to indicate that it can't complete the request. In this case, the response entity would likely contain a list of the differences between the two versions in a format defined by the response Content-Type.

3) 401 Not Authorized

> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication" [43].

For any other use case that you have, it varies. I would probably go with number 2 if there is truly no standard way of encoding specific errors.

Comment: Blake, thanks for the answer. 1: 400 is too much generic error code - it can serve as a "collector" for all kinds of errors we are uncertain about only in case if we introduce sub-codes to differentiate beetween all these possible 400s. 2: 409 - I agree, I thought about it too. 3: 401 - I disagree, because the third example implies that the problem is unrelated to the credentials user supplies (they are valid and ok in this case). Anyway if one goes with 401 in this case, then again he likely will need to differentiate 401 requests by introducing sub-codes.